# How do you add Node to the frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have been coding with a React frontend and a Node/Express backend. But sometimes, I only need some plain Javascript without React, but still want the benefit of NPM and other Node modules. What is a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a module bundler of some kind. There are many options including [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/), Browserify, Gulp, and Parcel.

For Webpack, for example, from their example docs, the process could be:

- Install webpack with `npm install webpack` and install `webpack-cli`
- Install a module you want to use on the frontend, eg lodash
- In `src/index.js`, import lodash: `import _ from 'lodash';` and use it as needed. (You can also import other modules from NPM or from other places in your source code)
- Set up `webpack.config.js` if you need custom build configuration settings
- Run webpack to build the project: `npx webpack`. A single bundled JavaScript file will be created which contains all your source code *and* the imported Lodash's source code.

Comment: @DonaldZhu I think you'll find Browserify a lot easier to get running with than Webpack.  At least, I did.  :-)  After using Webpack for years, getting frustrated with the piles of configs, and now two separate CLIs for the same task, I went back to Browserify.  Most things can be built without a specific config, although admittedly I have ended up setting Terser for most projects.  Your mileage may vary.